# SonarQube running in Azure DevOps, Error: Could not find 'java' executable in JAVA_HOME or PATH

Tags: azure-devops, sonarqube, azure-pipelines

I am trying to run a SonarQubeAnalyze in Azure DevOps to scan a React App.

SonarQubeAnalyze started by throwing the following Error: "Could not create the Java Virtual Machine"

[image]

I added a variable to limit Heap size of the JVM, Error still persisted. JVM Error went away when I added the JAVA_HOME.

[image]

The AgentPool(installed image) already comes with Java JDK 11 installed.
That can be confirmed with running `java --version` inside the agent:

[image]

SonarQubeAnalyzer is still not finding java:
[image]

I did a `chmod 755 /usr/lib/jvm/msopenjdk-11-amd64/bin/java` in the file (https://community.sonarsource.com/t/could-not-find-java-executable-in-java-home/36504/3), but still getting the same error: "Could not find 'java' executable in JAVA_HOME or PATH."

I ran a `ls /usr/lib/jvm/msopenjdk-11-amd64/bin/` inside the Agent and I can see java in there:
[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated on how I can resolve this issue.

Comment: Is this your local build agent or MS Hosted?

Comment: @ShamraiAleksander they are MS Hosted, but they are MS Hosted.

Comment: Try adding a [`JavaToolInstaller`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/java-tool-installer-v0?view=azure-pipelines) step.

Comment: @DanielMann added that and still no luck "Cannot start JVM"